# If every proper subgroup of an infinite group $G$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

If every proper subgroup of an infinite group $G$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian ?

I know there is an infinite abelian with this property(every proper subgroup is cyclic). But I was unable to find any example of a non abelian group with this property. So I try to prove it.

If there exist $a,b \in G$ such that $ab \neq ba$ then we take $<a,b>$(Group generated by a and b).

If $<a,b>$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then $<a,b> = <c>$ for some $c \in G$.

So $ab=ba$.
So $<a,b> = G$.

Again I was not able to complete the proof.

It is clear to me if such non abelian group exist then it must be generated by exactly two elements.
So how can I proceed ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the infinite dihedral group is a counterexample.

Comment: @Randall The subgroup of $D_{\infty} = \langle r, s \ |\ s^2=rsrs=1\rangle$ generated by $\{r^{42},s\}$ is isomorphic to $D_{\infty}$, which is not cyclic.

Comment: @Dennis, ah right, that's obvious.

Comment: @Dennis, It would be helpful if you could explain how ⟨r,s | s2=rsrs=1⟩ generated by {r^42,s}

Comment: @EUQAH Note that $D_\infty$ is the group of isometries of $\mathbb{Z}$: $r$ is the map $x\mapsto x + 1$ that slides the number line by one unit, and $s$ is the map $x\mapsto -x$ that reflects across zero. If you only allow translating by multiples of 42, then you get isometries of $42\mathbb{Z}$, which is the same as $\mathbb{Z}$ but scaled up, so it has the same isometry group. That's the intuition, but to verify algebraically, we can define a homomorphism $D_\infty \to D_\infty$ that sends $r\mapsto r^{42}$ and $s \mapsto s$, and check that the relations work (hint: $(srs)^{42}=sr^{42}s$).